# laravel can't retrieve session when redirect

Tags: laravel, session

in laravel 5.4

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{

   public function checkLogin(Request $request)
   {
      Session::put('admin','yes');
      return redirect('mobiles');
   }
}

class MobilesController extends Controller
{
      public function __construct()
      {
         if( ( Session::has('admin') ) )
           { dd('admin');}
        else
           { dd('not admin'); }
     }
}
```

it prints 'not admin' so what happen to the session , if i prints the admin session in class checkLogin it prints normally

Answer (score 1):

Since **L5.3**, you cannot a access to the session in the controller's constructor. You have to use a closure :

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        echo Session::has('admin') ? 'admin' : 'not admin';
        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.3-session-in-constructors

Answer (score 0):

you have to use laravel flashed-session-data

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

`return redirect('mtest2')->with('admin','yes');`

so modify your code like this

```
class AdminController extends Controller {

    public function checkLogin(Request $request){
        return redirect('mobiles')->with('admin',true);
     }
 }

 class MobilesController extends Controller {

     public function __construct() {

       if( session()->has('admin') ){ 
          dd('admin');
       }else{ 
          dd('not admin'); 
       }
     }
 }
```

Here is updated code if you do not want to use Flashed data

```
class AdminController extends Controller {

    public function checkLogin(Request $request){

        $request->session()->put('admin',true);
        return redirect('mobiles');
     }
 }
```

it should work.

Comment: I do not think that session flash is adequate for this situation (login/authentication) as OP wishes to achieve. Flashed data will be available only for the next request.